# I want to make a link or url which will download my video, like if someone press the link the video should be downloaded in their mobile

Tags: url, video, hyperlink

I want to make a link or url which will download my video,  like if someone press the link the video should  be downloaded in their mobile....

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the hyperlink tag and insert your file under href:

```
<a href="video.mp4" target="_blank">Download this video</a>
```